# gradle task by environment using docker plugin, JIB

Tags: docker, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew, jib

I have setup 2 gradle tasks, each for one environment (e.g. DEV and PROD) in build.gradle file.

```
plugins {
   id "com.google.cloud.tools.jib" version "2.4.0"
}

version = 0.1
group = my.company

jib {
    from {
        image = "openjdk:14-slim"
    }
    to {
        image = "my-registry.some-provider.com/my-app"
        tags = [version, 'latest']
    }
    container {
        mainClass = "${group}.Application"
        jvmFlags = ["-Xms${findProperty('MEMORY')?:'256'}m", '-Xdebug']
        ports = ['80']
        volumes = ['/data']
        environment = [
            'VERSION': version
            'DATA_DIR': '/data',
            'APPLICATION_PORT' : '80',
            'DEVELOPMENT_MODE' : 'false'
        ]
    }
}

task prodtask(type: sometask!) { } 

task devtask(type: sometask2) { }
```

I run these tasks in command line with gradlew command,

```
./gradlew i devtask (in DEV) and 
./gradlew i prodtask (in PROD)
```

How to run these 2 tasks separately in dev and prod environment with docker image built using JIB plugin?

Comment: Could you describe more details in your post about the relationship between these two tasks and JIB task?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the point between `jib` and `dev` / `prod` environment, but you can simply add a gradle `env` property, and based on the value you can dynamically select what to do, for instance in a gradle kts script:

```
...
val env: String by project
when (env) {
  "dev" -> tasks.register<Task>("sometask") {
      doLast { println("hello") }
      dependsOn("jib")
    }
  "prod" -> tasks.register<Task>("sometask2") {
      doLast { println("world") }
      dependsOn("jib")
    }
  else -> throw RuntimeException("Unknown env")
} 
...
```